# Alt keys (Alt and ALt Gr) doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: keyboard, 12.10, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No application switcher in compiz settings manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237355/no-application-switcher-in-compiz-settings-manager)

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 12.10. I didn't want to upgrade my 12.04, because when one upgrades the system, sometimes something fails, so I installed Ubuntu 12.10 afresh, all was perfect. Then I installed nvidia drivers, Filezilla, `oracle-java7-installer`, GIMP and VLC. these are the only programs that I have installed.

Now, when I try to open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, nothing happens. When I'd just installed my <kbd>Alt</kbd> key worked fine, but now any shortcut that uses <kbd>Alt</kbd> doesn't work.

I opened the keyboard settings, and I see when I press any of the keys and <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the key in the screen doesn't show up like the other keys do, so it seems like I don't have the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

I searched for solutions on the internet and tried things such as **Keyboard Preferences > Behavior Settings > Options > <kbd>Alt</kbd> / <kbd>Super</kbd> keys**, but the problem persists.

Comment: I think I can confirm the problem. After upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10 `Alt+Tab` does not work anymore although it is enabled in system keyboard settings.

Comment: Hi posted answer there, Hope that going to help you.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. He says "any shortcut that uses Alt, doesn't work", not just the application switcher.