# No application switcher in compiz settings manager

Tags: gnome, compiz

I had the problem of no <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> in Gnome classic on Ubuntu 12.10 so after reading a bit I found a solution. The solution consisted of installing CompizConfig Settings Manager and enabling application switcher. The problem is that I cannot find that icon it is not in the Window Management tab of compiz.

Ok After many frustrating hours. I have completely uninstalled the gnome-shell using this as a guide: [Remove Gnome Shell completely after installing it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65200/remove-gnome-shell-completely-after-installing-it) . I then reinstalled it and the problem was still there. Then I took a look at a fresh install of 12.10 and the same problem was there as well. Then I took a look at a fresh install of 12.04 and the problem wasn't there. The option to add application switching was there and I was able to enable it. I have no idea why that option is not in 12.10.

Comment: You can add an answer your own question so people can find it!

Comment: Yea just got enough reputation to do it. It's done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright I finally got it. On ubuntu 12.10 there are a few plug-ins missing in compiz. So you have to install compiz-plugins-extra:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
```

voila the options appears. Then you can follow this guide: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1968630

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.10, the static application switcher is not available after installing ccsm (it was with 14.04), and one needs to install compiz-plugins-extra as mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Type as ccsm in your terminal and then It will Open your Compiz manager.Then Select Window Management, Select Application Switcher and it will open another windows as shown in second Image . There enable Application Launcher will be there . Select It.

and you are done. Hope that helps.

[image][image]

Comment: In the window management tab there is no Application Switcher. I only have Grid, Move Window, Place Windows, Resize Window, Scale and Snapping Windows.

Comment: Hi But I my self Have tried this amigo, may be we both are missing something. How you have installed gnome-classic ?

Comment: I used this guide. http://www.filiwiese.com/installing-gnome-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

Comment: yeah Now I got . Uninstall it by " sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-shell " and remove the PPA too Then try with sudo apt-get install gnome-shell .then try again.

Comment: I uninstalled it with " sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-shell " and then I removed the PPA. Then I reinstalled with apt-get install gnome-shell and it was the same problem. After uninstalling it again I noticed that the gnome classic was still there does it come with ubuntu?

Comment: Ok do one thing , Now again uninstall it and run . sudo apt-get autoremove autoclean then give a restart and then try again . The problem for your case is you are not using the one of Ubuntu's . so you need to get it done to get such feature in here.

Comment: I have edited the question with a few things I tried.

Comment: if running Unity - Scroll down to "Ubuntu Unity Plugin". Choose the tab "Switcher". Disable the alt-tab and shift-alt-tab key bindings. ("Key to start the switcher" and "Key to switch to the previous window in the Switcher".
Click the "Back" button.